# What is wrong with this javascript date difference calculate function?

Tags: javascript

Any idea why this function doesn't work properly in Internet Explorer?

```
function days_between(check_in, check_out)
{
    var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; 
    var firstDate = new Date(check_in);
    var secondDate = new Date(check_out);    
    var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay));
    return diffDays;
}
```

in internet explorer it shows **NaN** as result.

im calling this function in this date format

```
var check_in = "2012-02-09";
var check_out = "2012-02-12"; 
var range = days_between(check_in, check_out);
```

Regards

Comment: what does `alert(new Date(check_in).getTime())` and `alert(new Date(check_out).getTime())` give you? `NaN`?

Comment: In which format you deliver the dates? what do you send to the function?

Comment: Salman A yes it gives NaN and im passing date in this format "2012-02-09"  this function works fine in firefox and chrome

Comment: This works on IE8 with inputs `June 3, 2001` and `June 10, 2001`. It correctly renders `7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format you're passing (yyyy-mm-dd) isn't supported by `Date`. See the note [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) that says it must be in a format parsable by `parse`. See here for acceptable parse formats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't support `Date.parse` or passing `"2012-02-09"` (with ISO dates) to `new Date`, you need to parse it yourself and pass `new Date( 2012, 1, 9 )` or use a [`Date.parse` shim for ISO dates](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in creating the Date Object

Date objects are created with the Date() constructor.

There are four ways of instantiating a date:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Most parameters above are optional. Not specifying, causes 0 to be passed in.

Once a Date object is created, a number of methods allow you to operate on it. Most methods allow you to get and set the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and milliseconds of the object, using either local time or UTC (universal, or GMT) time.

All dates are calculated in milliseconds from 01 January, 1970 00:00:00 Universal Time (UTC) with a day containing 86,400,000 milliseconds.

Some examples of instantiating a date:

```
var today = new Date()
var d1 = new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00")
var d2 = new Date(79,5,24)
var d3 = new Date(79,5,24,11,33,0)
```

(Taken from http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)

Comment: FYI, there are some folks around here that will down on you for referencing w3schools. The MDN references are deemed much more accurate and broader. Their snootiness aside, I think they're correct (but still snooty). Cheers! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the date arguments in an incorrect format. You can expect javascript to support these formats:

```
MM-dd-yyyy
yyyy/MM/dd
MM/dd/yyyy
MMMM dd, yyyy
MMM dd, yyyy
```

To fix your immediate problem, you can use `replace()` to format your arguments.

```
function days_between(check_in, check_out)
{
    var firstDate = new Date(check_in.replace('-' , '/'));
    var secondDate = new Date(check_out.replace('-' , '/'));    
    var diffDays = Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime()) / 86400000);
    return diffDays;
}
```

And by the way, you can replace oneDay with a constant.